# ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ToastContainer' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called

Tags: angular, typescript

I didn't get this error while running ng serve and ng build, only while running `ng build --prod` I get this error. how to fix it, let me know.

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ToastContainer' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ng2-toastr on angular 8, try using ngx-toastr

Comment: I am Using ngx-toastr only not ng2-toastr

Answer (score 0):

add this to Index page

```
<link href="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js"></script>
```

it'll solve the issue for me on Angular 9